Difference between Chainer ConvolutionND (N=3) and Pytorch nn.Conv3d
I'm trying to convert a model from Chainer code to the PyTorch. I use nn.Conv3d to replace ConvolutionND from Chainer, but the problem is that they produce different outputs.
To examine the issue, I created two simple classes:
class ChainerModel(link.Chain):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChainerModel, self).__init__()
        with self.init_scope():
            self.conv1a = ConvolutionND(3, 3, 64, 3, 1, 1)
            self.conv1a.W.data.fill(1)
            self.conv1a.b.data.fill(1)

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.conv1a(x)


class PyTorchModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyTorchModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1a = nn.Conv3d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.conv1a.weight, 1)
        nn.init.constant_(self.conv1a.bias, 1)

Then, I initialised the input, weights, and biases all to 1 to see if there is any difference in how both implementations work.
input_data = np.ones((8, 3, 16, 112, 112), dtype=np.float32)

When I forward this input to both models, the results are the same. However, once I use my actual input data (float values), they output different values.
Why do they produce different results, although the input is the same in this situation, and how can this be fixed?
